# How to make wget *not* overwrite/ignore files?

Tags: wget

I have a list of 400 websites from where I'm downloading PDF's. 100 of these websites share the same pdf name: templates.pdf
When running wget, it either ignores the pdfs that have name "templates" or overwrites them. I was searching for a command that would make a new templates2.pdf for 2 hours, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you do a web search for the phrase "manpage of wget"?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `wget` is to use the `.1`, `.2` prefixes when a file is downloaded multiple times into the same target directory. This appears to be what you are asking for. (The poorly named `-nc` option causes subsequent downloads of files with the same name to be ignored, which you don't want).

If the default behavior is not what you want, the `-O` option looks promising, as it allows you to _choose) the output file name. [Here is a brief article explaining its use](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/wget-save-different-filename/).

Of course, if you go the `-O` route, you'd need to ensure the output file does not exist, and do the suffix incrementing on your own.

Comment: Doesn't no clobber say explicitly say just what I'm trying to avoid? "When ‘-nc’ is specified, this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will refuse to download newer copies of ‘file’"

Comment: Yes, apologies, you did say you did not want to ignore subsequent downloads. Can you clarify why the default behavior is not working for you?

Comment: I expect the default behavior to download me template.pdf, template1.pdf, template2.pdf, etc... All I'm seeing after all downloads however is template.pdf

Comment: That's unfortunate... a script with a counter and `wget -O` might be your best bet then; sorry I have no other ideas.